# IntelliJ Idea 13.1.4 and JDK 1.8.0_11

Tags: intellij-idea, intellij-13, java-8

I am running IntelliJ Idea 13.1.4 on OS X 10.9.4. I have installed JDK 1.8.0_11. Writing any programs in Java shows the error that 'String' could not be resolved and one of the suggestions is to set the JDK. Even after specifying the JDK correctly (there is just one option) I am unable to resolve the errors. I have tried invalidating cache and restarting the ID to no avail. Even after reinstalling the application exhibits the same issue.

Comment: So you're sure that the syntax overall is valid?  IntelliJ may report false positives if the syntax is invalid.  Start with a simple "Hello world" - create a class with only a `main` method, and declare your string in there.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was resolved by installing JDK 1.8 update 20.